# Forcefully update/reset home screen widget extension configuration

Tags: ios, swift, widget, widgetkit

I am creating a home screen widget for iOS.  On long press, you can edit the widget:

[image]

I've set up an `IntentHandler` class and everything works great.  The only thing that doesn't, is, that I cannot reset certain chosen configuration.  For instance, below, `List` is dependent on `Workspace` (List is a child of Workspace), and if the user changes the `Workspace`, I would like to reset the `List` to nil.  This is because some a specific list only exists in one workspace. Instead, if the user changes the workspace, the list stays the same, and because `Show If Parent` is set to `has any value`, it shows the same config, which is inaccurate.

I've tried showing/hiding the value based on a parent/child relationship, but since `Workspace` is dynamic, I can only hide the child if parent has no value:
[image]

It doesn't allow me to hide the child if the parent property is equal to a certain value.  (In my case, show list if list.workspaceID === workspace.id.

Is there any way to set this up?  Or maybe programmatically update the widget extension value with some function I am unaware of?

```
class IntentHandler: INExtension, ConfigurationIntentHandling {

    func provideTeamOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<Team>?, Error?) -> Void) {

        RequestManager.getTeams() {
            (response, error) in

            if let response = response, let responseDictionary = response["response"] as? [JSONDictionary] {

                let teams = responseDictionary.map { (team) -> Team in
                    return Team(identifier: (team["id"] as! String), display: team["name"] as! String)
                }

                let collection = INObjectCollection(items: teams)
                completion(collection, nil)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func provideSubcategoryOptionsCollection(for intent: ConfigurationIntent, with completion: @escaping (INObjectCollection<SubCategory>?, Error?) -> Void) {
        var subcategoryArray = [SubCategory]()
        if let team = intent.team, let teamID = team.identifier {
            RequestManager.getSubcategories(teamID: teamID, queryString: nil){
                (response, error) in
                
                 if let response = response, let projects = response["projects"] as? [JSONDictionary] {
                   
                    let subcategories = responseDictionary.map { (subcategory) -> Team in
                    return Sub(identifier: (subcategory["id"] as! String), display: subcategory["name"] as! String)
                 }
                    let collection = INObjectCollection(items: subcategoryArray)
                    completion(collection, nil)
                }
            }
        }else{
            let collection = INObjectCollection(items: subcategoryArray)
            completion(collection, nil)
        }
    }
}
```